# awk print value without quote sign

Tags: linux, bash, centos

I have this value

```
option 'staticip' '5.5.5.1'
```

I want to print only `5.5.5.1` without quote sign. I have use

```
cat /etc/filename | grep staticip | awk '{print $3}'
```

but the result come with `'5.5.5.1'`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Or, you can use `tr` to remove the offending characters:

```
cat /etc/filename | grep staticip | awk '{print $3}' | tr -d \'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use awk's `gsub()` function to change the quotes to nothing.

```
awk '{gsub(/'"'"'/, "", $3); print $3}'
```

Note this is really `gsub(/'/, "", $3)`. The ugliness comes from the need to glue quotes together.

Comment: @skwllsp Fixed the escaping. Certainly ugly though :(

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '$2=="staticip" && $0=$4' FS="'"
```

Result

```
5.5.5.1
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove the ' from the awk output you can use
`sed "s/^'//;s/'$//"`
This command removes the ' only at the beginning and the end of the output line and is not so heavy as to use awk and not so general if using tr.
awk is much bgiger in memory and tr removes all ' from the output what is not always intended.

Answer (score -1):

You could use awks substr function or pipe that to the cut command.  I leave you to read the man page for awk substr.